# Can following discrete logarithm problem be considered as difficult?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, complexity

For $m, m'$, is it possible to find $r, s, t$ such that $r^s = m$ and $r^t = m'$ in modulo $G$, where $G$ is a large prime.

Do you think is it relatively easy to find such $r$ from $m$ and $m'$? Consider that $m$ and $m'$ are arbitrary values.

Comment: The question is lacking crucial information, e.g. what type of group you're looking at (it is trivial for prime order groups, if the group order is known it is trivial to check for random elements (and thus find a generator)). And then you just use $s,t$ without definition, $m,m'$ are just given, but not what they are (we have to assume you mean integers).

Comment: Yes it would be trivial if we can simply check for all $r, s, t$. But considering $G$ is super large, I don't think that makes sense to me.

Comment: No, it's not trivial by checking all values. It is trivial because any element of the group is a generator, and therefore is a solution for $r$. The DLOG problem is finding $s$ or $t$, and that's hard, but that's not what you asked for - before the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the edit your question is basically a vaiant of the DLOG problem, and since you did not specify your group any further (let's call it $\mathbb{Z}_p$) any further, let's assume $p-1$ has a known factorization, which is quite standard for DLOG problems.

- Finding $r$ is trivial: Try random values for $r$, and check if the order is $p-1$. If you want to make it more efficient, calculate the orders of $m,m'$ first and find an element with the least common multiple order.
- Finding $s,t$ given $r,m,m'$ is just two instances of the DLOG problem, which are independently of each other.

Doing DLOG twice does not make the problem itself any harder with respect to a polynomially-bounded adversary - a small static factor like $2$ does not matter at all. And then, the DLOG problem is only hard, if there is at least one large subgroup and algorithms like [Pohlig-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) actually solve the problem in each subgroup individually and then assemble the solution.

If you're not familiar with algorithms for the DLOG problem, consider it like this: Factoring $p-1$ is easy, and with those prime factors we can apply a divide-and-conquer strategy: Solve the problem for each prime factor, and afterwards use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to assemble the solution. So it is not enough that $p$ is a large prime.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the the problem is not a discrete logarithm problem at all.

Secondly , given $s$ and $m$ it is easy to find $r$. Same turns out with $t$ and $m'$. One can easily calculate $r$ with the following algorithm.

1.Calculate the order of the prime $\phi(G) = G-1$.

2.Calculate $d=s^{-1}mod\ \phi(G)$ using extended euclIdien algorithm.

3.Calculate $m^d=(r^{s})^{s^{-1}}=r\ \ mod \ G$

As both  extended euclIdien algorithm and exponentiation can be computed in polynomial time of the length of $G$. The problem can be solved easy.

But what indeed is difficult is the following.

Consider you are given $r$,$m$ and $G$ .
 Computing $t$ such that $m=r^t\ mod \ G$ is hard.
This is widely known as discrete logarithm problem.

Comment: Sorry I restated my question. The question here is that I need to find all of $r, s, t$ that satisfies the above relation. Neither of $r$ nor $s,t$ are given.

Comment: Well, now that turns into a very well known Diffie-Hellman problem. Which can be reduced to a discrete logarithm problem. You can trivially state $r=m$ and $s=1$ which immediately converts the second problem to a discrete logarithm problem.

Comment: Yes that is true. But the little difference here is that we can set the arbitrary $r$ as a candidate. If $r = m$, then it would be same as solving the discrete logarithm problem. But as $r$ is choice of yours, can this still remain as the difficult discrete logarithm problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that`s a variant of the discrete logarithm problem.

You can trivially state $r=m$ and $s=1$. Now now computing $t$ is the same as solving discrete logarithm problem.

Comment: Your argument only shows that the problem can be reduced to DLP (*assuming* that $m,m'$ are from the right distributions). That does not imply that they are equivalent.

Comment: Actually, if the factorization of the group order is known, this is exactly the DLOG problem (multiple instances, but still) for finding out $s,t$. Finding any $r$ is trivial (just pick any generator). Assembling a solution is basically the same as in the [Pohlig-Hellmann algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm)